# How to find the details of sent item through bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am implementing one app related to Bluetooth.

In my requirements, I want to get the details of sent and received data through bluetooth.

I get the details of received data through bluetooth from the folder `/sdcard/bluetooth`. It is fine, but problem is, I want to get the details of sent data through bluetooth.

Does any one know the solution?

Comment: what details related to the sent data are you specifically looking for?

Comment: sent data means what he sent,for example he sent a image like sample.jpg  .Then i want get the detilas of that like name,path..If it posible please help me.thanks

Comment: i am not getting it. If i send an image using bluetooth then that image has to be present in my storage..so accessing the storage eg: /sdcard can help me get the details..am i right?

Comment: Are you looking for the opposite of a Broadcast receiver? So you can monitor data being "Broadcast" from the phone (via bluetooth)?

Comment: if don't mind please provide some sample,thanq